# How to fix laravel migration error 42501?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

What does the following error mean?

> SQLSTATE[42501]: Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR:  permission denied for schema public at character 14 (SQL: create table "migrations" ("id" serial primary key not null, "migration" varchar(255) not null, "batch" integer not null))?

It occurs when performing migrations in laravel-9 with postgreSQL database

Answer (score 1):

That probably means that you are using PostgreSQL v15, but rely on the standard permissions on older versions, where everybody had `CREATE` permission on schema `poblic`. You will have to grant the permission to the user.